# MVC4 Send ViewModel to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to pass a ViewModel that consists in two List to a Controller, but I'm getting null results in the controller Action. I've been searching the web for answers but I can't seem to find something I could use.

I've tried to make it work according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299669/mvc-4-viewmodel-not-being-sent-back-to-controller) but I'm stuck.

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel
{
    public string TituloOrigen1 { get; set; }
    public string TituloOrigen2 { get; set; }
    public List<ConciliacionItem> noConciliadasOrigen1 { get; set; }
    public List<ConciliacionItem> noConciliadasOrigen2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model RECON.DAL.ViewModels.ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel
@using RECON.Resources

@using (Html.BeginForm("GrabarConciliacionManual", "ConciliacionItem", FormMethod.Post, new { ListaAConciliarManual = Model }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.noConciliadasOrigen1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.noConciliadasOrigen2)

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h3>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TituloOrigen1)
        </h3>
        @{
    Html.RenderPartial("_ListaItemsAConciliarManual", Model.noConciliadasOrigen1);
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h3>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TituloOrigen2)
        </h3>
        @{
    Html.RenderPartial("_ListaItemsAConciliarManual", Model.noConciliadasOrigen2);
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
        <br />
        <button type="submit" id="btnConciliarManual" class="btn btn-primary botonera">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

}
```

And this is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult GrabarConciliacionManual(ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel ListaAConciliarManual, string motivo)
    {
    }
```

What I'm to process are two lists of the same kind of model, which actually works if I pass only a List to the action (I've done this before), but due to usability purposes I have to show both lists separated.

I don't need the strings of the ViewModel, just the lists. The other parameters, "string motivo" works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added code of partial view:

```
@model List<RECON.DAL.Models.ConciliacionItem>
@using RECON.Resources
@using GridMvc.Html
@using RECON.DAL.Models

@{
    IEnumerable<ConciliacionItemDiseno> conciliacionItemDiseno = new List<ConciliacionItemDiseno>();
    var itemDiseno = (IEnumerable<ConciliacionItemDiseno>)ViewBag.ConciliacionItemDisenos;
}

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                              {
                                  columns.Add(foo => foo.ClaveConciliacion, true).Titled("ClaveConciliacion");

                              columns.Add(foo => foo.Id).Titled("Id");

                              columns.Add(foo => foo.OrigenDescripcion).Titled("Origen");

                              // VARCHARS

                              conciliacionItemDiseno = itemDiseno.Where(x => x.Campo == "Varchar1");
                              if (conciliacionItemDiseno.Any())
                              {
                                  columns.Add(foo => foo.Varchar1)
                                                  .Titled((conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Titulo") != null ? conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Titulo").Valor : string.Empty))
                                                  .Css((conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Align") != null) ? ((conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Align").Valor == "C") ? "text-center" : (conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Align").Valor == "R") ? "text-right" : "text-left") : string.Empty)
                                                  .SetWidth((conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Width") != null) ? conciliacionItemDiseno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Diseno.Codigo == "Width").Valor : string.Empty);
                              })
```

Comment: Can you post useful snippets from the _ListaItemsAConciliarManual - partial view, thanks

Comment: Yup, I just did that. Thanks.

Comment: hummm, you are doing too much in your views, they are doing filtering etc etc. Seperate your collections from the view model may be...

Comment: I have to use the Mvc.Grid [link](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) in this project, so I have no choice regarding that. Nevertheless, I found out that if I send to the controller 2 List<model> instead of the viewModel and in the partial view I use standard html instead said grid, I receive the lists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem parting it in several pieces: Since I needed to post a List with every object available, what I did was this:

1) I created 3 lists, 1 to send to the view, and 2 for presentation. Once I filled the collection I needed to send to the view, I filled the other 2 and then passed them to the view into 2 ViewBags.

2) In the view, I filled the partial views with the content of both ViewBag for displaying, but kept only the "working" list into consideration.

3) The controller only receives the "working" list, and does it job like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a hidden input (or any form control) to a collection of complex objects. If you inspect the html generated by

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.noConciliadasOrigen1)
```

it will be something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="noConciliadasOrigen1" value="System.Collection.Generic.List[ConciliacionItem]" />
```

and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set

```
model.noConciliadasOrigen1 = "System.Collection.Generic.List[ConciliacionItem]";
```

so model binding fails and the property is `null`

If you did want to post all the values of all the properties in the collection, then you need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ConciliacionItem`. But you do not appear to be editing any properties of your collections (in fact you do not appear to be editing anything at all from the code you have shown) so its unclear why you would want to degrade performance by generating a lot of extra html and post it all back unchanged. Assuming you are editing something, if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then just repopulate those collections again.

You also need to remove `new { ListaAConciliarManual = Model }` from your `BeginForm()` method. Again if you inspect the html your generating you will understand why this will never work.

Comment: This was really illustrating. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GrabarConciliacionManual", "ConciliacionItem", FormMethod.Post, new { ListaAConciliarManual = Model }))
```

to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GrabarConciliacionManual", "ConciliacionItem", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: I've done it before asking, still getting null values. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a constructor to `ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel` and in that constructor initialize the two lists.

Something like this:

```
public class ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel
{
    public ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel()
    {
        this.noConciliadasOrigen1 = new List<ConciliacionItem>();
        this.noConciliadasOrigen2 = new List<ConciliacionItem>();
    }

    public string TituloOrigen1 { get; set; }
    public string TituloOrigen2 { get; set; }
    public List<ConciliacionItem> noConciliadasOrigen1 { get; set; }
    public List<ConciliacionItem> noConciliadasOrigen2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I could try, but to what end? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner regarding c# OOP. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the model ItemsConciliacionManualViewModel that you have with the one I suggested which has the constructor List's initialization